# Python sqlite3 correct use of commit

Tags: python, sqlite

I m building a web crawler and I wanted to save links in a database with informations like type, size, etc.

and actually I don't know when I should commit the database (how often)

in other terms: is it a problem if I commit the database every 0.1 second?

Comment: If performance is not a problem, why not commit it everytime when you add something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of logical correctness, you should `commit` every time a set of one or more queries that are supposed to execute atomically (i.e, all of them, or else none of them, execute) is finished.

There is no connection between this logical correctness and any given amount of time between `commit`s.  In your vaguely-sketched use case, I guess I'd be committing every time I'm done with a whole web page -- what I want to avoid is likely the committing of a web page that's "partially done" but not completely so -- whether that means 100 msec, or 50, or 200 -- why should that duration matter?